# Access SQL Date Format

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

How can I retrieve a record based on a Date property? I'm trying:

```
WHERE Meetings.[MDate] = '16/12/2011'
```

which is the format I use but I get :

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

---

Problem solved: It should have been:

```
WHERE Meetings.[MDate] = 16/12/2011
```

No quotation marks.

Comment: What tool is involved?  MSaccess?

Comment: Beware the LCID settings. It varies from server to server and can change the way Access deals with dates. For example, here in Brazil, we use `'dd/mm/yyyy'` to set values and `#mm/dd/yyyy#` to select in where clauses. Crazy? No, just MS things.

Answer (score 14):

For where clauses use

```
columnName = #mm/dd/yyyy#
```

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to use the SQL date format: '#2011-12-16#'

Answer (score 6):

Use the cast to `DATETIME` function, `CDATE()`, which will honour the machine's regional settings. That said, it still a good idea to use an unambiguous date format and the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format is a good one.

Also note that Access doesn't have a date data type: its sole temporal data type is `DATETIME` and, as its name suggests, *always* has a time element accurate to one second time granule, even if that time happens to be midnight. Therefore, it is a good idea to always include a time value to one second time granule in all `DATETIME` literals e.g.

```
WHERE Meetings.MDate = CDATE('2011-12-16 00:00:00');
```

Another advantage to the above is that the Access UI will not attempt to reformat the `DATETIME` literal because it is held as a string.