# SQL STATE 37000 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax Error or Access Violation

Tags: sql, odbc, powerbuilder

Good day!

I get this error:

SQL STATE 37000 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax Error
 or Access Violation, when trying to run an embedded SQL statement on
 Powerscript.

I am using MsSQL Server 2008 and PowerBuilder 10.5, the OS is Windows 7. I was able to determine one of the queries that is causing the problem:

```
SELECT top 1 CONVERT(DATETIME,:ls_datetime)
into :ldtme_datetime
from employee_information
USING SQLCA;

if SQLCA.SQLCODE = -1 then
    Messagebox('SQL ERROR',SQLCA.SQLERRTEXT)
    return -1 
end if
```

I was able to come up with a solution to this by just using the `datetime()` function of PowerBuilder. But there are other parts of the program that is causing this and I am having a hard time in identifying which part of the program causes this. I find this very weird because I am running the same scripts here in my `dev-pc` with no problems at all, but when trying to run the program on my client's workstation I am getting this error. I haven't found any differences in the workstation and my `dev-pc`. I also tried following the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa269541%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), but the problem still occurs.

UPDATE: I was able to identify the other script that is causing the problem:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  f_datediff
//  Computes the time difference (in number of minutes) between adtme_datefrom and adtme_dateto
////////////////////////////

decimal ld_time_diff

SELECT top 1 DATEDIFF(MINUTE,:adtme_datefrom,:adtme_dateto)
into :ld_time_diff
FROM EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION
USING SQLCA;

    if SQLCA.SQLCODE = -1 then
        Messagebox('SQL ERROR',SQLCA.SQLERRTEXT)
        return -1
    end if

return ld_time_diff
```

Seems like passing datetime variables causes the error above. Other scripts are working fine.

Comment: What's the purpose of the colons?

Comment: Wherever constants can be referenced in SQL statements, PowerScript variables preceded by a colon (:) can be substituted. --this is from the powerbuilder help file.

Comment: Any chance the deployed ODBC driver isn't the same as the one you're using on your development machine? Maybe the deployed driver isn't licensed for what it's doing. (I'd also love to ask the question as to why you're using ODBC as opposed to something closer to native, but that might be beyond a small "fix".)

Comment: Check the ODBC drivers, it's not unknown for bugs to exist http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa269541(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @Mr Fuzzy I've tried that too but nothing happened

Comment: @terry I haven't really used any except odbc. I used to directly connect to sql when I was still using older versions of powerbuilder. sadly pb 10.5 doesn't support direct connection to mssql anymore..

Comment: @gmevangelist: No direct connection? Not true; there have always been "native" connections, although MS's definition of native has evolved. At 10.5, you're asking for some pretty far back recollections, but at that time the "native" connection was OLEDB; SNC might have been there, might have been introduced in 11.0. The deprecation by MS of the interface that the PB MSS driver used doesn't mean there wasn't a native connection anymore.

Comment: @Terry I'm really far behind with regards to the PB version I am using haha. I must have misunderstood this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sybase.public.powerbuilder.database/2it-dH41OOA) when looking for a way to connect to SQL. (I use MSS before for PBv5 yes version 5.) Seems like I need to learn more about this. Thanks

Comment: @jmevangelist Yes, there's a lot of information missing in that, so a lot of room for misinterpretation. MSS used DB-Lib as the interface, and that was deprecated in SQL Server 2005. Going forward, OLE-DB, and a specific variant SNC, are the interfaces to use. OLE-DB got implemented in PB10, and SNC in 11. ADO and OLEDB can be used too, but they add layers; they have their place, though. For your case, I'd make sure the ODBC driver is the same between development and deployment, and your problem isn't a bug or license restriction in the driver.

Comment: @Terry just checked the version of the ODBC drivers and they are the same. If its not a bug, license restriction or driver difference then I dont know where to look anymore.. Anyway just tried using OLE DB.. its working fine here in my dev mach. I hope this will also work fine on the other workstations. I'm just starting to develop the software so its not that much of a problem. Thanks

Comment: I hope this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526494/access-sql-date-format

Answer (score 0):

- Create a transaction user object inherited trom transaction.
- Put logic in the sqlpreview of your object to capture and log the sql statement being sent to the db.
- Instantiate it, connect to the db,  and use it in your embedded sql.
- Assuming the user gets the error you can then check what was being sent to the db and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your first statement should be the second parameter to CONVERT function.
It's type is not a string, it's type is an valid expression
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

So I would expect that your

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,:ls_datetime)
```

would evaluate to

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, 'ls_datetime')
```

but it should be

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, DateTimeColumn)
```

The error in your second statement could be that you're providing an wrong datetime format.
So please check if your error still occurs when you use this function
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql

with the correct datetime format you're using