# Microsoft Access Type Conversion Failure?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is the query returning an error:

```
INSERT INTO Receipt(TransactionID, TransactionDate, TransactionTime, EmployeeID, CustomerID, EmployeeEmail, EmployeePhone, BarcodeID, StoreID, StorePhone)
VALUES ('o8237y837vy837', '2021-03-26', '3:00', 'at73917391', '098462', 'alext@yahoo.com', '347-745-3432', '2374984827548', '0065', '453-674-2341');
```

Here is the table it's adding to:

```
CREATE TABLE Receipt

(
TransactionID varchar NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
TransactionDate DATE NOT NULL,
TransactionTime TIME NOT NULL,
EmployeeID varchar
);
```

I added  the columns EmployeeID (varchar), CustomerID (varchar), EmployeeEmail (varchar), EmployeePhone (varchar), BarcodeID(varchar), StoreID(int), StorePhone(varchar) separately.

Comment: Date delimiter is #, not single-quote '

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might accidentally be casting the `TransactionDate` to a string. [Try removing the apostrophes around the date.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526494/access-sql-date-format) Also check to see if you are using the correct date format, usually this is `##/##/####`, it appears you have used a custom format `##-##-####` make sure the database is willing to accept that format for dates.

Answer (score 0):

StoreID is a number, so don't attempt to insert a string:

```
VALUES ('o8237y837vy837', #2021-03-26#, #3:00#, 'at73917391', '098462', 'alext@yahoo.com', '347-745-3432', '2374984827548', 65, '453-674-2341');
```

When displaying the StoreID, apply a format like "0000".

If that doesn't fit you, change the data type of the field to VarChar.