# Retrieve a range of dates from a Access database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a database with a table of dates then with values of Revenue and Expenditure in the records.
I need to get the Revenue for the last week, month, quarter (3 months) and past year. (Same for Expenditure)

I know how to get it for one specific date. Would I have to iterate through to find the values for each or..?

TIA

(Attached is the table with the data called 'Finances)

[image: Table With Data]

This line is what i thought would would work but it doesn't? It returns a blank sheet.

```
SELECT * FROM Finances WHERE [Date] >= 07/03/2022 AND [Date] <= 25/02/2022
```

Comment: Just ask for all the dates which fall between the dates at either end of the range you want. Not literal syntax (because I can't remember the last time I had the misfortune to be asked to do anything using MS Access and have happily forgotten it all) but here's the general idea: `WHERE YourDateField >= YourDesiredStartDate AND YourDateField <= YourDesiredEndDate`

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: @ADyson I understand Start date. What do you mean by DateField and the rest?

Comment: @Ben711Gaming Put in the name of the relevant column ("field") in place of `YourDateField`.

Comment: Yes exactly - `YourDateField` represents whatever column/field in your table holds the date that you're trying to filter by. And I hope the End Date bit is as obvious as Start Date?

Comment: @ADyson ah yes thank you. I'll have a mess with Access' SQL engine then try implement it into VB

Comment: @ADyson This line is what i thought would would work but it doesn't?

`SELECT * FROM Finances WHERE [Date] >= 07/03/2022 AND [Date] <= 25/02/2022`

Comment: Doesn't work in what sense? An error? Unexpected output? As I said earlier, my memory is vague but I'm pretty sure in Access date literals have to be surrounded by #s? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526494/access-sql-date-format might be relevant, depending on what problem you're having.

Comment: @ADyson APologies, When i run the query, it returns a blank sheet. (Bearing in mind I'm running this in Access so far so I don't have to piss about with VB)

Comment: Well obviously I can't see your source data or table definition, so I've no way of knowing whether it ought to return any results or not. You can edit the question, if you want to provide more info.

Comment: @ADyson It should be attached now

Comment: Date constant in MS-Access query should be enclosed between # and written written with the format MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Indeed, as I said earlier have you tried with the #, and with using a non-ambiguous or default format, as per that link? Also, I assume the `Date` column is configured as a Date type in access, not plain text or anything silly like that?

Comment: @ADyson Ah yes, those pesky Americans. I suppose I'll have to reformat that in VB when using parameters in my code -_-

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: @Ben711Gaming Well, 07/03/2022 gets seen as 7 divided by 3, then divided by 2022, so about 0.00115.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like this:

```sql
Select
    *
From
    Finances
Where
    [Date] Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 0)
```

That is for the previous month. Other options:

```sql
# The last month:
Where
    [Date] Between DateAdd("m", -1, Date()) And Date()

# The last three months:
Where
    [Date] Between DateAdd("m", -3, Date()) And Date()

# The last week:
Where
    [Date] Between DateAdd("ww", -1, Date()) And Date()
```

Many other options are possible, for example for exact quarters, financial years, etc. Study my project [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).